# How to render a chart inside a tabView with PrimeFaces

Tags: java, charts, jsf-2, tabs, primefaces

I need to display a lot of charts on some kind of status page. The charts should be grouped in `tabView` and `accordionPanel`. This setup works nice with *PrimeFaces 2.2.1*. Because of some features of the new version (and because the charts are no longer *Flash*) I am trying to migrate to *PrimeFaces 3* (3.0.M3 at the moment).

```xml
<p:tabView>  
  <p:tab title="One">  
    <p:pieChart value="#{myBean.myChartOne}" />
  </p:tab>
  <p:tab title="Two">  
    <p:pieChart value="#{myBean.myChartTwo}" />
  </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

With PrimeFaces 3 the charts don't show up. There is a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2535) describing this problem and stating that there should be lazy loading for charts in 3.0 M4.

**Update:**

I am now using PrimeFaces 3.0 M4-snapshot with lazy loading charts. It looks like this:

```xml
<p:tabView>  
      <p:tab>
        <p:accordionPanel>  
            <p:tab title="All time">  
                <p:commandButton value="load chart" type="button" onclick="onTimeChartAll.init(); buttonOnTimeChartAll.disable();"
                    widgetVar="buttonOnTimeChartAll"/>
                <p:pieChart value="#{myBean.onTimeChartAll}" lazy="true" 
                    widgetVar="onTimeChartAll" />
            </p:tab>
            <p:tab title="30 Days">  
                <p:commandButton value="load chart" type="button" onclick="onTimeChart30Days.init();buttonOnTimeChart30Days.disable();"
                    widgetVar="buttonOnTimeChart30Days"/>
                <p:pieChart value="#{myBean.onTimeChart30Days}" lazy="true" widgetVar="onTimeChart30Days" />
            </p:tab>
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </p:tab>
    [...] <!-- and so on -->
</p:tabView>
```

I can open a tab and click on the button to load the chart. Now I want to find a solution to automatically load the chart when a tab is opened. The  Is there a solution to automatically load the chart, when the tab is opened? For `p:accordionPanel` and `p:tabView` there is the `onTabShow` attribute, but I think I would need it for `p:tab`. Or is there a possibility to address the `widgetVar` of the currently opened tab via `onTabShow` and `var`?

Comment: Just one idea: I once had problems displaying charts but only in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, ...). For me it helped to use the `<f:view contentType="text/html">`. Don't know if it is related but you could give it a try.

Comment: It is not a bug but a common limitation of hidden containers and children of these components that need dimension calculation. Current workaround is to use lazy charts, similar to editor.

Comment: @CagatayCivici According to the bug report lazy charts are available with the next milestone-release. That why I tried with the latest nightly. How can I use lazy loading with the current version?

Comment: @MattHandy I also stumbled on this a while ago. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris So I will silently leave this discussion since you have Primefaces lead developer caring for you ;-)

Comment: See http://wiki.primefaces.org/display/General/Migration+Guide+to+3.0 : Taglib namespaces are changed as http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui -> http://primefaces.org/ui

Comment: @Adam "Note that this change is applied after M3 release." That is a valuable piece of information (and the solution for my M4 problem) I overlooked. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primefaces project lead just wrote a [blog post](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=1485) saying that this should be fixed in 3.0.M4:

> We are glad to share that upcoming PrimeFaces 3.0.M4 has a generic solution for this, so on page you don’t need to deal with these as PrimeFaces handles these under the hood for you.

Comment: I'm also really looking forward to this release. Although not being a solution for now, I gladly accept your answer: This will be as good as it gets. :) Thanks